# Changing SHA-1 constants an functions: Does it affect security?

Tags: sha-1

I have been looking into the SHA-1 algorithm. I found that there are a set of functions and constants in the algorithm that have been standardized [(section 5 of RFC 3174)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3174#section-5). If I want to use SHA-1, which I know is not advisable, does changing the constants and altering the functions have a positive effect on the security of the algorithm, assuming the attacker does not now of this alteration?

Comment: Note that altering these constants will completely void most / if not all cryptanalysis of the algorithm. Thus I'd _suspect_ the answer to be "you may be good or you may not be, we don't know, but you probably should just use SHA-256 or SHA-3 or even SHAKE-128-160 if you can".

Comment: @SEJPM i wouldnt use sha-1 for any production application, I just wondered if it would enhance it, in theory. But I understand your point about the cryptanalysis. Thanks.

Comment: "assuming the attacker does not now of this alteration?" clear violation of kerckhoffs's 2nd principle.

Comment: I really only ask this question to get a more thorough understanding of the effects the functions and constants have on such an algorithm. I thought that it would not impact the algorithm so much that you could say it is not sha1 anymore but sha-ish. A thought I had was that if I just altered the functions and constants that it would be like ‘salting’ the algorithm instead of the input. I understand that it is a violation of kerchhoffs principle. It was more of a thought expiriment I could not figure out the effect myself..

Comment: I use bcrypt in my webapps anyway for all password storing purposes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing values of the constants and / or the logic of functions from SHA-1 would just create a different algorithm. Depending on how large the changes are you could then say that the altered algorithm is similar or belongs to the family of "SHA-1-like" algorithms.

The effect on security:

We just don't know. You could of course try to do some large-scale calculations, i.e. try to see if known attacks of SHA-1 still apply to "altered-SHA-1", or try to find collisions, look for indications if the [avalanche-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect) still is good enough and so on.

Additional:

It's not good practice to rely on [security by obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), for multiple reasons:

1. In your case the security of your model is based on the fact that the attacker would never gain information of your used algorithm.
2. You can't be certain that your altered-SHA-1 is even more secure than the already vulnerable SHA-1. And because you haven't released this algorithm to the public you would have no idea if it's vulnerable.

In this case it's good practice to follow [Kerckhoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle).

Comment: Changing the IV is generally safe, since hashing two blocks is equivalent to hashing the second block with an IV set to the digest of the first block.

Comment: @forest That's kind of an argument in reverse, but the idea that the algorithm would be insecure for other blocks except the first seems correct to me :)

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't suggest heuristically changing constants. However, there is a method with rigorous foundations that considered using randomized hashing in digital signatures. This method has the advantage that one can assume less from the hash function, and thus if the hash function is not "fully" collision resistant, the signature scheme can still be secure. In the method described in [Strengthening Digital Signatures via Randomized Hashing](https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2006/41170039/41170039.pdf) by Halevi and Krawczyk, one only needs target collision resistance, which is much weaker than full collision resistance. Of course, this only helps in the context of signatures.

Answer (score 3):

I did some more research about the topic and someone did some experimenting on this. He found that when changing the constants for the initial state, the security of SHA-1 is compromised.

It is an interesting read and is indeed a good answer to my question. One should not alter the constants because it can affect security in a negative manner. He showed that he could choose constants such that particular files collide. If I were to randomly alter my SHA-1 function, I might create these collisions that can be exploited, though unlikely it still can happen.

> This is the webpage of the Malicious SHA-1 project, a research project that demonstrates how the security of the SHA-1 hashing standard can be fully compromised if one slightly tweaks some of the predefined constants in the SHA-1 algorithm. That is, we show that systems using “custom” versions of SHA-1 may include backdoors exploitable by the designers. Such custom versions of cryptographic standards are typically found in proprietary systems as a way to personalize the cryptography for a given customer, while retaining the security guarantees of the original algorithm.
>
> How are the modified constants weaker? They aren’t.
>
> Unlike operational parameters such as rotation values, the exact values of the round constants we modify do not have a direct impact on the security of the hash function (although there are some values that would weaken the algorithm by introducing undesirable statistical properties, for example choosing all 0s).
>
> Our attack only exploits the fact that the designer has freedom in choosing the constants, not any particular weaknesses. To third party analysis, malicious SHA-1 remains as strong as the original SHA-1: the backdoor is “undiscoverable“, it can only be exploited by the designer.

https://malicioussha1.github.io/

Comment: In retrospect, this is obvious; if we allow the attacker to treat the round constants as free variables, then we'd expect them to have enough flexibility to design a collision fairly easily.  I would expect a similar result to apply to the SHA-2 hashes....

Comment: This is an interesting read, but it assumes that the constant values are not constant. If you allow the values to be changed per message then yeah, all bets are off. But that's not exactly what was asked.